# Corona sdk text input

Tags: sdk, native, coronasdk, textfield

I have looked at example code that uses the native textField on Android. I would like to be able to type into the text field without having to touch a button to show the text field, and then touch inside the text field to start typing. Is there a way to show the text field and set focus to it, where I can start typing without touching other buttons. I am working on an app and I don't want the users to have to take extra steps to begin typing text. Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call native.setKeyboardFocus(yourField) to show the keyboard.

http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/native/setKeyboardFocus.html

Comment: Thanks. That does work, but still requires the textField to be touched to start typing. What I'm attempting to accomplish is bring up the keyboard and set the blinking cursor in the textField, so a user can just start typing without the extra motions.

Comment: You should be able to call the native.setKeyboardFocus() function and pass it the handle for the field and it should bring up the keyboard and put the cursor in the field.

Comment: I am using native.setKeyboardFocus() and that works. Thanks for the help.